# I can't find a differential drive package using rplidar with dc motors and no encoders

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, moveit, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need help to find the appropriate drive controller, so far most seem to implement a pid with the encoders as a feed back mechanism.

Surely someone has already done this.... Looking for a recommendation of how to implement this.

Here are the specifics:

all of the differential drive packages I have found so far seem to require encoders.
My bot has an rplidar on it which is supposed to be able to provide odom via hector slam.(still having issues with this, but will post a separate thread)
I do not have encoders.
The goal is to have the rplidar provide the odom and the send the appropriate commands to the arduino that runs the l298 motor controller, this is a four wheel bot with only two motors, tank steer style.
Hector slam package installed and Moveit planning is in process, but obviously need this to respond to a navigation stack, I believe my arduino **MUST respond to cmd_vel** so that is what I am trying to make happen.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257176/i-can%27t-find-a-differential-drive-package-using-rplidar-with-dc-motors-and-no-encoders/) by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2017-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The title confused me, so you are not finding drivers for rplidar because they have built everything for you.

Instead, you want a driver for L298? Or, a differential PD control for the motor drive?

Plus, writing a PD control is not very hard...

---

Originally posted by [HexC](https://answers.ros.org/users/29717/hexc/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-03-16**:
the motors are essentially open loop at the arduino level. the are no encoders to measure the distance traveled , so a pid at this level is not possible, unless I tried to bring the lidar odom data back down to the arduino. These I believe this would have a bit too much lag, but, I could be wrong.

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-03-16**:
The hope is that the navigation stack will look at the laser odom and the output geometry twist/ cmd_vel message for the arduino to follow... hope I did not confuse this any further...

**Comment by [HexC](https://answers.ros.org/users/29717/hexc/) on 2017-03-23**:
I think you can fake the motor odom since you said it is a four wheel tank drive bot. How is the driving scenario, will slipping happens a lot. If you bot is not a perfect square and can not do in place turning. You will end up with some inaccurate data. I did the same thing and the results are fine